# Show JDialog on Windows taskbar

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm trying to display a `JDialog` in Windows. How do I show a `JDialog` (like `JFrame`) on my Windows taskbar?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A dialog itself cannot have a task bar entry, but you can construct a frame that does not have any visible effect and use it as a parent for the dialog. Then it will look like the dialog has a task bar entry. The following code shows you how to do it:

```
class MyDialog extends JDialog {

    private static final List<Image> ICONS = Arrays.asList(
            new ImageIcon("icon_16.png").getImage(), 
            new ImageIcon("icon_32.png").getImage(),
            new ImageIcon("icon_64.png").getImage());

    MyDialog() {
        super(new DummyFrame("Name on task bar", ICONS));
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        super.setVisible(visible);
        if (!visible) {
            ((DummyFrame)getParent()).dispose();
        }
    }
}

class DummyFrame extends JFrame {
    DummyFrame(String title, List<? extends Image> iconImages) {
        super(title);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setIconImages(iconImages);
    }
}
```

Comment: But there is no use in using modal dialog if we are using like this right?

Comment: Actually, there is: if there is a common login dialog that is used even at run-time (to re-prompt for credentials due to expired authentication), then if the developer desires a JDialog for its ability to be modal for the run-time case, then this approach helps re-use that JDialog code during the first-time login case too when there is nothing to be modal to. Some tweaks required.

Answer (score 38):

I found the answer to your question because I had the opposite problem. I had a JDialog that was showing in the taskbar and it took me forever to figure out how to prevent it from showing. Turns out **if you pass a `null` parent to the JDialog constructor, your dialog will show in the taskbar**.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog((Dialog)null);
```

The cast to `java.awt.Dialog` is to avoid the ambiguous constructor.

Comment: Alternatively, cast to `Window`. Both work. This seems to be the intended design. Do this rather than defining your own class.

Comment: Why isn't this the top answer? It's so much better and simpler

Answer (score 16):

```
class MyDialog extends JDialog {
    MyDialog() {
        super(null, java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType.TOOLKIT_MODAL);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Dialogs are shown in the taskbar, when they have no owner. The possibility to have unowned Dialogs was added to AWT in Java 6. Unfortunately, at this time, the Swing class `JDialog` had already constructors with a predefined behavior regarding absent or `null` owners, working around the limitations of the previous Java versions. This behavior can’t be changed due to compatibility concerns.

Thus, when you use the old constructors `JDialog()` and those accepting a `Frame` argument, they exhibit the behavior compatible with the older versions, creating an invisible dummy `Frame` as owner if none is specified. So the Dialogs created this way are always owned by a Frame.

This is also incorporated into the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog--):

> NOTE: This constructor does not allow you to create an unowned `JDialog`. To create an unowned `JDialog` you must use either the `JDialog(Window)` or `JDialog(Dialog)` constructor with an argument of `null`.

The named constructors are new to Java 6, as the possibility to have a Dialog owned by another `Dialog` or a `Window` was added in that version as well. Since these new constructors do not have to be compatible to a previous version, they can support unowned Dialogs. This is the reason why [the solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25533860/2711488) works.

You may also use the constructor taking a `ModalityType` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14261194/2711488) as [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog-java.awt.Window-java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType-) is also new two Java 6 and supports unowned dialogs. But you don’t need to create a subclass of `JDialog` to use this constructor.

Comment: Also explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19117575/2711488) but I took the opportunity to go a bit into the details of the reasons…